# Do I need a transformer to use this lamp in the US?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, adapter

I bought a lamp that was advertised as having 90V - 260V US power supply, and it has an LED screw-in type light bulb.

I received the lamp and it has a type C plug adapted to type A for US power. However, the tag says, "220V - 240V ~ 50 Hz, E27 Max 40W."

It has the CE certification, which I think means it's safe to use in the US, am I correct? And I don't know what the other 2 symbols mean.

Is this lamp safe to use as-as, long-term, by plugging into my US wall plug (120V)?

Thanks for your help!!

[image: tag for lamp: v information]

Comment: Does the lamp have any form of electronic switch or dimmer? or just a plain old mechanical switch? what does it say on the bulb?

Answer (score 1):

### That mark actually means "Chinese Excrement".

You think I'm kidding.

Overseas makers of the cheap & shoddy are regularly forging quality marks.  Far and away their favorite is the CE mark; they either mess up the mark [accidentally-on-purpose](https://siloscordoba.com/blog/corporate/china-export-is-not-ce-a-symbol-to-cause-confusion/), or render it correctly but put it on total junk.  A proper CE mark is only applicable to bricks-and-mortar companies located inside the EU, who ships the product from their EU warehouse (not Amazon's) to an EU customer, and it is a **self**-certification by that company.  Naturally every Chinese maker self-certifies everything, and the EU can't do anything about it because they don't have assets in the EU.

The USA is not a member of the EU, so the EU can do nothing about products shipped from China to the US.  CE has become a self-fulfilling prophecy; "I see it a lot" (on junk) "so it must be legit!"

Actually, in the US, products for retail sale must clear an independent third party testing lab (which CE is not). The biggest labs are UL (Underwriter's Laboratories, surely you've heard of them), CSA, and ETL/Intertek. All will assign a "file number" as part of their listing; you can spot a fake UL when there's no file number nearby, but China doesn't fake UL marks very often.

Probably because UL is a private nonprofit company with an army of attack lawyers.

Here's [more on marks](https://www.consumerreports.org/smartphones/symbols-on-smartphone-charger/).  Note the UL stamps with C/US and file number. Also notice, no CE anywhere.  There'd be no reason to put CE on a charger with a Type A plug.

All this is to shortcut all the safety standards that make products safe.  It's not insulated well enough not to energize the chassis or start a fire with arcing, the components aren't tested not to make toxic smoke if burned, the line cord's wires aren't thick enough, the insulation isn't tough enough, and they haven't paid for independent lab testing.  That makes the price lower, which is what draws you to it.

### Is it safe?

It certainly does not meet the standards for any US product.  It was skated by Customs because Customs is overwhelmed and has higher priorities.

Can it function on 120V?  The sticker plainly says no, but that kind of sloppiness is why they can't get certified.  Reality? Maybe, maybe not. It depends if the fixture contains only wires, or has some sort of smart or powered thing (like a dimmer) in its internals.

- If it's only wires - I wouldn't say it's safe at any voltage, but if it were safe at 230V, it'll be safe at 120V,  and the functional voltage will be decided by what kind of screw-in bulb you use.  If you use a 120V bulb you'd be fine.
- If it has electronics inside - then it's hit and miss, *but no lab anywhere has tested what happens, so don't be surprised if it starts a fire*.

### The [other marks](https://www.consumerreports.org/smartphones/symbols-on-smartphone-charger/)

Square in square means the appliance is double-insulated; that means one insulation failure won't cause you to be shocked; it will take two.  *Don't count on this being true; it's probably faked*.

The house and arrow says "Bring it in from out of the rain" which means it's indoors/dry location only.

Answer (score 1):

The “CE” stamped on the unit is a symbol used in Europe noting that its “Conformity European”.

https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/everyday-tech/question135.htm

It’s a certification in order for it to be sold throughout Europe. Yes, you’ll need an adapter. If you’ve ever been to europe , you know you need an adapter to use your shaver, phone charger, etc.